# What is the best practice for ouputting data from a collection on an ASP.net Page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages, code-behind

I've ported a page from classic ASP to ASP.net. Part of what happens in this page is that a collection of custom types is generated and then displayed via `Response.Write()` commands. I'd like to get the business logic separated out into a code behind file (and maybe move this all into a user control), but I can't seem to figure out how I'd actually display the collection once it's been generated. I want to specify a master page here, too, so the code can't stay inline. Here's a very stripped down version of the current code:

```
<%
Dim objs as ArrayList = New ArrayList()

For i = 0 To 2
    Dim obj as Obj = New Obj()

obj.setProp1("ASDF")
obj.setProp2("FDSA")

objs.Add(obj)
Next i
%>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Property 1</th>
        <th scope="col">Property 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<%
For Each obj As Obj In objs
Dim objProp1 As String = obj.getProp1
Dim objProp2 As String = obj.getProp2
%>                  
    <tr>
        <td><% Response.Write(objProp1)%></td>
        <td><% Response.Write(objProp2)%></td>
    </tr>
<%
Next
%>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What is the ".net" way of doing this?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using v2.0

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use the ListView then...

Comment: It looks like I'll be getting .Net 3.5 installed on the server, then :)

Comment: If you're about to start installing .NET on your servers you may as well choose .NET4!

Comment: I was under the impression that .Net 4 was still unreleased. Since it's actually out, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also take a look at the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) control which is a newer version of the repeater that Joe R mentioned.  There's a great tutorial on what you can do with a ListView on [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx).

Your code would basically turn into something along these lines:

```
<asp:ListView id="ListView1" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
    <LayouTemplate>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Property 1</th>
                    <th scope="col">Property 2</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <asp:Placeholder runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder" />
             </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayouTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("objProp1" )%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("objProp2" )%></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

[These guys](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/BestPractices.ashx) consider using `Eval` to not be a good practice, but it made writing the example easier.  If you're presenting read only data, don't forget to turn off ViewState or your pages will get very big very quickly.

**EDIT** Also found a [feature comparison chart](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/09/06/comparing-listview-with-gridview-datalist-and-repeater.aspx) between the different list style controls here.

Comment: This is all in the LayoutTemplate. This has no item to repeat. You are missing the ItemTemplate and the itemPlaceholder that needs to go in the LayoutTemplate (in .NET3.5 - .NET4 you dont need too ;)) Other than that you are right - ListView over Repeater any day.

Comment: Okay, so I'm going with the ListView. It seems the most flexible and I have the option of stepping up to v3.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET2 your best bet it the repeater. Something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rpt1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"> 
    <HeaderTemplate> 
        <table> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th scope="col">Property 1</th> 
                    <th scope="col">Property 2</th> 
                 </tr> 
             </thead> 
             <tbody> 
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr> 
                     <td><%# Eval("objProp1" )%></td> 
                     <td><%# Eval("objProp2" )%></td> 
                 </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
             </tbody> 
        </table> 
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in your code behind you bind the data like this:

```
rpt1.DataSource = objs;
rpt1.DataBind();
```

This would be c# though - hope that's okay

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like a repeater or datagrid and bind it to a List<> that you can create in your Business Logic layer.